# Permutations in Ruby - unsure how to handle

Tags: ruby, arrays, permutation

I am trying to output an array of 10-element arrays containing permutations of 1 and 2, e.g.:

```
 [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
 [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
 [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
 ...etc...
 [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]]
```

I have done this with smaller arrays, but with (10):

```
 a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
 a = a.permutation(10).to_a
 print a.uniq
```

...this apparently is too big a calculation- after an hour running, it hadn't completed and the ruby process was sitting on 12GB of memory. Is there another way to come at this?

Comment: Are you looking for `[1,2].repeated_permutation(10).to_a`?

Comment: Nice one @Stefan - had forgotten about that one

Comment: Note: sometimes it helps to do a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation first, before trying to run an inefficient algorithm. We don't know how big an array really is in Ruby, but we can assume that we need at least a pointer to the beginning and an integer for the length plus one integer for each of the elements. In reality, an array is going to be *much* bigger than just a pointer and an integer, there's also going to be an object header, for example. But even for this *extremely* low estimate, we see that you generate 60 Terabytes of data.

Comment: And even if you had a 5GHz CPU and were able to generate one array element per clock cycle, it would take over 20 minutes to fill those 60 Terabytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, check size of that permutation

```
a.permutation(10).size
 => 670442572800
```

It's huge. What you can do instead is to use `Array#repeated_permutations` on smaller array. Check it here:

```
b = [1, 2] # Only unique elements
b.repeated_permutation(10) # Returns enumerable
b.repeated_permutation(10).to_a # Creates array with all of permutations
```

Those permutations are already unique (which u can check by printing it size with and without `Array#uniq` )

Comment: Hi Bartosz, when I try that, all I get for output is #<Enumerator:0x00000002e99fd8>

Comment: `b.repeated_permutation(10).to_a`

Comment: Exactly as @mudasobwa wrote you have yet use `Enumerable#to_a` method. Other way is to just iterate through them with for example `Enumerable#each` method. That depends on what you want to do next with those permutations.

Answer (score 4):

The approach you've gone down does indeed generate a lot of data - 20!/10! or about 600 billion arrays. This is clearly very wasteful when the output you are after only has 1024 arrays

what you are after is closer to the `product` method on array

```
[1,2].product(*([[1,2]]*9))
```

The product method produces all the possible combinations by picking one element from each of the receiver and its arguments. The use of splats and the `*` method on array is just to avoid writing `[1,2]` 9 times.

Comment: Hi Frederick- that worked, I will look into the product method so I can understand why. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one, Freddie. `20!/10! = 10.times.reduce(1) { |t,e| t*(e+10) } #=> 335,221,286,400`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland slightly more - your product included 10 instead of 20

Comment: Ah, yes. With `t*(e+11)`, what you reported (about 670 billion). What a difference +1 makes.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Don't use this... it's slower by a factor (10 times slower) then running**: `b= [1,2]; b.repeated_permutation(10).to_a`

What you're looking for is actually a binary permutation array...

So taking that approach, we know we have 2**10 (== 1024) permutations, which translated to the numbers between 0 and 1023.

try this:

```
1024.times.with_object([]) {|i, array| array << ( ("%10b" % (i-1) ).unpack("U*").map {|v| (v == 49) ? 2 : 1}  ) }
```

Or this (slightly faster):

```
(0..1023).each.with_object([]) {|i, array| array << ( (0..9).each.with_object([]) {|j, p| p << (i[j] +1)}  ) }
```

You take the number of options - 1024. For each option (i) you assign a number (i-1) and extract the binary code that comprises that number.

The binary code is extracted, in my example, by converting it to a string 10 digits long using `"%10b" % (i-1)` and then unpacking that string to an array. I map that array, replacing the values I get from the string (white space == 32 && zero == 48) with the number 1 or (the number 1 == 49) with the number 2.

Voila.

There should be a better way to extract the binary representation of the numbers, but I couldn't think of one, as I'm running ob very little sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that is similar to the approach taken by @Myst, except I've used [Fixnum#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) to convert an integer to a string representation of its binary equivalent.

There are `2**n` integers with `n` digits (including leading zeros), when each digit equals 1 or 2 (or equals 0 or 1). We therefore can 1-1 map each integer `i` between `0` and `2**n-1` to one of the integers containing only digits `1` and `2` by converting `0`-bits to `1` and `1`-bits to `2`.

In Ruby, one way to convert `123` to binary is:

```
123.to_s(2).to_i      #=> 1111011
```

As

```
2**9 #=> 512 
(2**9-1).to_s(2)      #=> "111111111"
(2**9-1).to_s(2).to_i #=> 111111111
```

we see that when comparing numbers between `0` and `511` (`2**9-1`), the binary representation of `123` would have two leading zeros. As we need those leading zeros to make the conversion to `1`'s and `2`'s, it is convenient to leave the binary representation of each numbers as a string, and pad the string with zeros:

```
str = 123.to_s(2).rjust(9,'0') #=> "001111011"
```

That allows us to write:

```
str.each_char.map { |c| c.eql?("0") ? 1 : 2 } }
  #=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```

We can wrap this in a method:

```
def combos(n)
  (2**n).times.map { |i| i.to_s(2)
                          .rjust(n,'0')
                          .each_char
                          .map { |c| c.eql?("0") ? 1 : 2 } }
end

combos(1)
  #=> [[1], [2]] 
combos(2)
  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]] 
combos(3)
  #=> [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2],
  #    [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]] 
combos(4)
  #=> [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 2, 2],
  #    [1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2],
  #    [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 2],
  #    [2, 2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]] 
combos(10).size
  #=> 1024
```